# Adjust alpha in post-hoc-power when bonferroni corrected before?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, statistical-power, bonferroni

I was wondering whether I need to adjust my alpha when testing the power of effects for which I have adjusted for multiple testing.

This is what I did:
Tested the effects of 8 (generalized) linear mixed models (in R via `lmer`-function as implemented in `lme4`-package). I bonferroni corrected alpha (0.05/8). Now, I would like to do a post hoc power simulation via `simr`. Do I also need to set alpha to 0.05/8 ?

Comment: Are those 8 models nested models (i.e., you just keep adding parameters onto a base model, and you test which one performs best using Likelihood ratio tests)?

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I did

Comment: Post-hoc power analysis is rarely a good idea. First, why did you correct for tests of nested models in your multivariate regression analysis? If I understand correctly, you're not interested in specific contrasts and you did correct the whole procedure (8 $\chi^2$ tests).